# Rechargeable battery calculation

Tags: batteries, capacity

The rechargeable battery info: 1900 mAH (1 battery)

A device that have input of 3V DC and output of 5 V / 500mA

If one rechargeable battery is inserted into the device, 
I can expect that it can provide me (1900 mAH / 500 mA of 3.8 hours) of output. (or it can last me for 3.8 hours)

So, if two rechargeable batteries are inserted in parallel,
I can expect 3.8 hours * 2 = 7.6 hours of output

So, if the device only provide me 1 hour of output with 2 batteries inserted, 
can I say that the circuit is faulty?
Suggestive that the device provide 3800 mA of output in 1 hour?

Also, a side note - the device becomes hot (temperature around 40 to 45 degree Celsius)

The 2 battery is insert into the following device:

[image]

Comment: What device, and could you perhaps share photos of how you have the batteries hooked up?

Comment: Depends on the batteries and what you consider to be your "discharged" voltage - in general the higher the discharge current, the lower the capacity obtained.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I have added the photo of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, stating the background based on the device now shown in the question:

The emergency charger shown is designed to provide 5 Volts at 500 mA, from 2 AA cells.

It is not clear from the device photo alone, and without specifications being provided, whether the device uses the batteries in series (*will not work with a single cell inserted*), or parallel as the question implies (*will work even with a single cell inserted*).

The circuit inside would be a boost converter, generating 5 Volts from a 1 to 3 Volt input. Typical boost converter efficiency is anywhere from 75 to 90 percent, depending on design and component selection.

**Assumptions:**

- 85% efficiency of boost converter for calculations
- [Eneloop HR-3UTGA](http://www.eneloop.info/fileadmin/EDITORS/ENELOOP/DATA_SHEETS/HR-3UTGA_data_sheet.pdf) NiMH rechargable AA cells
- The device uses the AA cells in parallel (series calculations also follow)

---

```
Output power: 500 mA @ 5 Volts = V x I = 2.5 Watts
Required input power:  2.5 / 0.85 = 2.941 Watts (at 85% efficiency)
Required min current: 2.45 Amperes (P / V, fully charged NiMh 1.2 Volt battery)
Required max current: 2.94 Amperes (with depleted battery, at 1 Volt)
```

Assume roughly equal split of current draw...

```
Min current from each: 1.225 Amperes
Max current from each: 1.47 Amperes
Actual capacity: ~ 1800 mAh per AA (Discharge graph in datasheet, between 1 and 2 A)
Capacity of 2xAA: ~ 3600 mAh
Time to Discharge: Capacity / Input Power = 3600 / 2941 =  ~1.224 hours
```

So, even in optimistic conditions, the charger is expected to deliver less than **1 hour 14 minutes of power**, from the above calculations. In reality, the current drawn would rise as voltage drops, thus causing faster depletion. Also, whichever cell has lower internal resistance due to manufacturing and life-cycle differences, would discharge first, loading the second into a quicker depletion.

**Thus the observed 1 hour of operation is not unexpected.**

---

Now, if the batteries were connected in series, as is possible, the following calculations change, the rest remain as above:

```
Required min current: 1.226 Amperes (fully charged, 2 x 1.2 = 2.4 Volts)
Required max current: 1.47 Amperes (with depleted battery, 2 x 1 Volt)
Actual capacity: ~ 1800 mAh per AA (Discharge graph in datasheet, between 1 and 2 A)
Capacity of 2xAA: ~ 3600 mAh
Time to Discharge: Capacity / Input Power = 3600 / 2941 =  ~1.224 hours
```

Thus, operation time would be about the same, but single battery operation would not be an option.

---

**Additional notes**:

- Typical boost converter efficiency reduces with increase in gap between input and output voltage. This impacts both faster depletion towards the end of battery charge, and lower efficiency for a parallel battery arrangement.
- Thus, realistically the **parallel battery option is likely to last much less** than with batteries in series.
- **The probable reason the device heats up more with rechargeable cells than with standard 1.5 Volt cells, is that the lower voltage causes greater efficiency losses.** Such losses are typically dissipated as heat in electronic devices.

Comment: Probably, you would like to answer the part 2 of this question as here - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/rechargeable-battery-charging-another-device-calculation ?

Comment: @Jack Answered that as well.

Comment: Yes, I have marked as correct. Would be great (and I will upvote) if you can write down the calculation like the way you answer this question.

Comment: @Jack Added estimation calculations there as well.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my comments at the part 2 of this question.